# Proof of Hölder's inequality for improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f,g\in \mathscr{R} (\alpha)$ then Hölder's inequality is also true for improper integrals.

[image]

I can't understand how they get the last equality. We know that $\int \limits_{0}^{1}f\,dx$ exists i.e. exists $\lim \limits_{c\to 0}\int \limits_{c}^{1}f\,dx$. How they conclude that exists also $\int \limits_{0}^{1}|f|^p\,dx$.

Can anyone explain it please?

Comment: The last integrals could be $\infty.$ Inequality still makes sense.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: @Jack, always where $\alpha$ must be replaced to $x$.

Comment: @zhw., Maybe i missed some conditions of theorem?

Comment: I thought it is the Riemann–Stieltjes integral. Look pretty much like an exercise in Rudin.

Comment: @Jack, I am thinking on this problem about 2 days but I have any results and can't find a full proof :(

Comment: "I can't understand how they get the last equality." Providing the reference where you come up with the exercise would improve the question a lot.

Comment: @Jack, http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math140/HW140B_2_solutions.pdf. Last page! I would be very grateful for you if you'll give the adequate proof!

Answer (score 3):

This is an exercise in Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis (Chapter 6 Problem 10c).

One has the assumptions that $p$ and $q$ are positive real numbers such that
$$
\frac1p+\frac1q=1.
$$

Also, $f$ and $g$ should be complex functions in $\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$. More precisely,  $f$ and $g$ are Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to some $\alpha$ over $(c,1]$ for any $c\in(0,1)$.

For any $c\in(0,1)$, one has (this is Chapter 6 Problem 10b)
$$
\left|\int_c^1fg\ d\alpha\right|\leq \left\{\int_c^1|f|^p\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/p}
\left\{\int_c^1|g|^q \ d\alpha\right\}^{1/q}.
$$
If 
$$
\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|f|^p\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/p}=\infty
$$
then
$$
\left|\int_0^1fg\ d\alpha\right|\leq \left\{\int_0^1|f|^p\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/p}
\left\{\int_0^1|g|^q \ d\alpha\right\}^{1/q} 
$$
is automatically true. Likewise for 
$$
\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|g|^q\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/q}=\infty.
$$
When 
$$
\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|f|^p\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/p}<\infty
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|g|^q\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/q}<\infty,
$$
you have the last equality in OP by *definition* of the improper integrals.

Comment: Very elegant proof! But you wrote that if $\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|f|^p\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/p}=\infty$ then inequality is automatically true. Why? What about if $\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|g|^q\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/q}=0$. Then RHS is $\infty \cdot 0$ it's smth undefined. Can you explain it please?

Comment: In that case, the left hand side is $0$ and by convention (see for instance Folland's Real Analysis), $\infty\cdot 0=0$. When dealing with Holder inequality in this case, $\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|f|^p\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/p}<\infty$
and 
$\lim_{c\to 0+}\left\{\int_c^1|g|^q\ d\alpha\right\}^{1/q}<\infty$ are supposed to be in the assumption for the sake of avoiding dealing with the extreme case. See Proposition 3 in [this note](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/245b-notes-3-lp-spaces/).

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of this? Sorry but in my country this blog is closed :(

Comment: You can also check the Holder's inequality in Folland's Real Analysis.